# Is it okay to omit "a" with "going for"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Is it okay to ask:
Are we going for film?

Or is it compulsory to add "a"?

Are we going for a film?

Comment: It's nothing to do with "going for". When we are talking about a single film, as opposed to "film" as a general topic, we always need an article. It doesn't matter whether we are going to it, coming from it, watching it, studying it, copying it, it is "a film" (or in context "the film").

Answer (score 3):

You can, but the meaning is different.

> Are we going for film?

Because there is no article, we have to assume "film" is plural, or a mass noun. If you needed film for your camera, you could use this sentence to mean to are going to a store to buy film.

But if "film" is singular, as in a "movie", you need to use an article.

> Are we going for **a/the** film?

though this would be an unusual way to say this ("film" more likely refers to the physical media). More likely, one would use something like:

> Are we going *to see* **a/the** movie?

Comment: I like this answer. One short footnote, about your final sentence: the word _see_ there is optional. We can (and often do) say, "Are we going to a movie?"

Answer (score 1):

A better sounding sentence would be:

> "Are we going to see a film?"

Or,

> "Are we going to the theater?"

Or,

> "Are we going to the cinema?"

There may be more, but these should suffice.